# How to change pitch in Audacity when dealing with notes and frequency only?

Tags: audacity, pitch, voice-manipulation

If I record my natural voice on Audacity, its pitch detection analyzes my voice at note C 3 at 128 Hz. If I record my voice using a voice changer (that changes the voice before it gets to Audacity), the pitch detection analysis has my voice at note D# 4 and 320 Hz.

If I record my natural voice on Audacity, how can I change the pitch in post from C3 @128Hz to the desired D#4 @320Hz, in effect mimicking the morphed voice (just done in post and not in real time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change pitch using Audacity, this is basically:

- Mark the region you want to change the pitch of.
- Go to "Effect" --> "Change Pitch..."
- Pitch "from" on the left side should show the analyzed C3.
- Set "to" on the right side to D#4.

You can also set the frequency values instead. I recommend to use the "Use high quality stretching" option. Note that this function was not part of very early Audacity versions (I'm lacking version numbers here.)

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_pitch.html) in case of further questions.

The result will sound unnatural, because plain pitch-shifting your voice also changes your voice's formants. Hence, when the pitch is set to your desired target frequency, you have to lower the formants back to their original frequency region (downwards some 15 semitones again) to get a more natural formants sound. Please have a look at [this discussion](https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?t=103120#p361598). You might have to experiment with the formant-pitch values to get best results.

In case you have access to a VST host / DAW or similar, you should maybe better try a professional plugin for changing pitch and formants (seperately), like maybe [this one](https://www.soundtoys.com/product/little-alterboy/). Audacity also works with some VST plugins, but I do not have any experience in it.